# DateUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to change the time of the server before executing the `preparedStatement`. The server time is `EDT` and I want to add 6 hours to it before using it in the preparedStatement.

Currently I am getting this error:

> DateUtils cannot be resolved.

How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
    String sql = "SELECT r.route "
            + "FROM routes AS r "
            + "JOIN arrivaltimes AS a ON a.route_id = r.route_id "
            + "JOIN stops as s on a.stop_id = s.stop_id "
            + "WHERE a.weekday = ?  "
            + "AND arrivaltime BETWEEN ? - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND ? + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE "
            + "AND s.name = ?";

    PreparedStatement preparedTime = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    Date d1 = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String serverTime = df.format(d1);
    java.sql.Time time = null;
    try {
         time = new java.sql.Time(df.parse(serverTime).getTime());
         Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(time, 6);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is DateUtils in your code? what's its packaging?

Comment: I have not imported it because when I hover over it nothing comes up! Just something to create it as class.. I tried to import it as this `import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;` but I am getting `The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved`?

Comment: I already have imported the date package `import java.util.Date;`

Comment: Have you copied this code from some snippet?

Comment: I have just found this line `Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(time, 6);` how to add hours to time .

Comment: I see you got the answer from @CodeNewbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your first comment, `The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved` means that the jar [commons-lang.jar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/commons-lang.jar.html;jsessionid=E6632FB610486A0C10CC564419F65C08) is missing from your classpath. Add the jar to your class path and the import will be successful.

As per your second comment, `java.util.Date` belongs to [rt.jar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.sun/jars/rt.jar.html) (and some other jars too). `DateUtils` and `Date` have a different package structure and available through separate jars.

Comment: I have not known that I have to import a jar to use it :)

Comment: I am getting this error when I execute it ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils`?

Comment: Now, there is also `commons-lang3` so one needs to use `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils`